# Is there any way to check the JSON string with express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

The `express-validator` attempts to examine the "email" field inside the "userData" object as follows.

```
userRouter.post('/', [
     header('type').isIn(...),
     body('userData').isJSON(),
     body('userData.email').trim().isEmail().isLength({ max : 50 })
], (req, res, next) => { ... });
```

However, "userData" is `req` in string form. It's being requested as part of the body.

In other words, the actual transition value is the same as the result of the code below.

```
userData = JSON.stringify({...});
```

I tried to find another way, but I'm thinking about a way because I have to use it on various platforms at the same time.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Try adding another middleware that parses `userData` as JSON

Comment: @Bergi Does it mean that I should try to configure middleware that I parse before the request arrives at the router?

Comment: No, because then the `isJSON()` middleware won't find a json text but rather an object. You either add the parsing step after that, or replace `isJSON` by the parsing (since it would already throw an error if the input is not json text)

Comment: @Bergi I understood. So I wrote a code that `check()` and `custom()` and checked the results I wanted roughly. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: You might want to [write an answer with your solution](/help/self-answer) then

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer, and it actually worked exactly.

```
userRouter.post('/', [
     header('type').isIn(...),
     body('userData').isJSON(),
     body('userData.email').trim().isEmail().isLength({ max : 50 }),
     check('userData').custom((userData) => {
        const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(userData);

        // Do something
     }),
], (req, res, next) => { ... });
```